# Unable to initialize global variable in javascript based game

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, phaser-framework

I have a flappy bird based clone game and I need to make a high-score feature for it. The high score disappears in a split second 'cause the game reloads and I don't know how to set the High Score as a global variable. Here is the link if you want to view it. (Warning: Lower headphone volume)

http://www.theindependentwolf.com/game/flappyWolf.html

```
// Initialize Phaser, and creates a 400x490px game
var game = new Phaser.Game(400, 490, Phaser.AUTO, 'gameDiv');

// Creates a new 'main' state that will contain the game
var mainState = {


// Function called first to load all the assets
preload: function() { 
    // Change the background color of the game
//         game.stage.backgroundColor = '#71c5cf';
    //background Image
    game.load.image('woods', 'woods.jpg');      

    // Load the bird sprite
    game.load.image('bird', 'whiteWolf2.png');  

    // Load the pipe sprite
    game.load.image('pipe', 'pipe.png');    


},

// Fuction called after 'preload' to setup the game 
create: function() { 
    // Set the physics system
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 400, 490, 'woods');


    // Display the bird on the screen
    this.bird = this.game.add.sprite(100, 245, 'bird');

    // Add gravity to the bird to make it fall
    game.physics.arcade.enable(this.bird);
    this.bird.body.gravity.y = 1000; 

    // Call the 'jump' function when the spacekey is hit
    var spaceKey = this.game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
    spaceKey.onDown.add(this.jump, this); 

    // Create a group of 20 pipes
    this.pipes = game.add.group();
    this.pipes.enableBody = true;
    this.pipes.createMultiple(20, 'pipe');  

    // Timer that calls 'addRowOfPipes' ever 1.5 seconds
    this.timer = this.game.time.events.loop(1500, this.addRowOfPipes, this);           

    // Add a score label on the top left of the screen
    this.score = 0;
    this.hiScore = 0;

    this.scoreLabel = this.game.add.text(20, 20, "Score: ", { font: "30px Arial", fill: "#ffffff" }); 
    this.labelScore = this.game.add.text(120, 20, "0", { font: "30px Arial", fill: "#ffffff" }); 

    this.hiScoreLabel = this.game.add.text(200, 20, "Hi Score: ", { font: "30px Arial", fill: "#ffffff" }); 
    labelHiScore = this.game.add.text(340, 20, "0", { font: "30px Arial", fill: "#ffffff" });   




        /*
    Code for the pause menu
*/




},

// This function is called 60 times per second
update: function() {
    // If the bird is out of the world (too high or too low), call the 'restartGame' function
    if (this.bird.inWorld == false)
        this.restartGame(); 

    // If the bird overlap any pipes, call 'restartGame'
    game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.bird, this.pipes, this.restartGame, null, this);              
},

// Make the bird jump 
jump: function() {
    // Add a vertical velocity to the bird
    this.bird.body.velocity.y = -350;
},

// Restart the game
restartGame: function() {
    // Start the 'main' state, which restarts the game

    if(this.score > this.hiScore ){
            labelHiScore.text = this.score;  
    }                

    game.state.start('main');
},

// Add a pipe on the screen
addOnePipe: function(x, y) {
    // Get the first dead pipe of our group
    var pipe = this.pipes.getFirstDead();

    // Set the new position of the pipe
    pipe.reset(x, y);

    // Add velocity to the pipe to make it move left
    pipe.body.velocity.x = -200; 

    // Kill the pipe when it's no longer visible 
    pipe.checkWorldBounds = true;
    pipe.outOfBoundsKill = true;
},

// Add a row of 6 pipes with a hole somewhere in the middle
addRowOfPipes: function() {
    var hole = Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1;

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        if (i != hole && i != hole +1) 
            this.addOnePipe(400, i*60+10);   

    this.score += 1;
    this.labelScore.text = this.score;  
},


};

// Add and start the 'main' state to start the game

    game.state.add('main', mainState);  
// document.getElementById("#startButton").onclick(function(){
//  alert("Hi");
    labelHiScore = 0;
    game.state.start('main'); 
// });
```

Comment: you need to store this value in either cookie, localStorage or the other new HTML5 persistant storage methods

Comment: What does `game.state.start('main');` do?

Comment: It starts the game over, from the beginning. I took this code from some open source place and I'm in the process of modifying it according to my needs. I'm new to the phaser.io game engine and don't completely understand it. @jfriend00

Comment: @jeff Uhmm.. Is there a way to just declare the variable somewhere in the same file without having to use cookies or store the variable in local storage?

Comment: Does `game.state.start('main');` reload the page?  I wanted to know what it actually does, not just in concept, but what the code actually does.  If it reloads the page, then all Javascript variables are reset so your high scores will be gone if they are only stored in Javascript variable.  If you want them to survive longer than a single page load, then you have to put them in LocalStorage, in a cookie or store them on a server.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah, it reloads every object in the game and the whole canvas as far as my understanding goes.

Comment: Well, that doesn't really tell us whether it reloads the page such that all JS variables to get reinitialized.  Anyway, if you want your high scores to persist, then you must store them in one of the places I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @jfriend00 ooh..sorry, I didn't read the entire comment. It reloads only the game window in the web page. So what you're saying is that for everybody who logs into my website, I have to create a session variabe/cookie so it can store their personal high score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try with following changes:**

In restartGame method:

```
restartGame: function() {
    if(this.score > localStorage.getItem("hiScore") ){
            localStorage.setItem("hiScore", this.score); 
            this.labelHiScore.text = localStorage.getItem("hiScore");  
    }        
    game.state.start('main');
},
```

In "labelHiScore" varaible Declaration:

```
this.labelHiScore = this.game.add.text(340, 20, ("hiScore" in localStorage ? localStorage.getItem("hiScore") : "0"), { font: "30px Arial", fill: "#ffffff" });
```

I hope you got what is the problem, in short

In restartGame method you are trying to assign score to window scoped variable instead of functional scope. 
Adding "this." will make to find variable in current object.

Also added score to local storage to preserve highscore, and when the game is reloaded picking value from local storage.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.